# error when trying to remove css class from classList in js LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I'm trying to implement slds tabs and in order to switch between tabs, I need to change the css classes. However, when I try to add or remove classes from the classList, it gives below error in console:

> Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'nonce-3744c145-c1b2-ab4c-c4f2-225fd8e53422' chrome-extension:
> 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.canary.lwc.dev *.visualforce.com
> https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/
> https://static.lightning.force.com". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is
> ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.

Below is the code snippet:

```
changeSelectedTab(event){
        //remove class for already selected tab
        this.template.querySelector('.slds-is-active').classList.remove('.slds-is-active');
    }
```

I also tried,

```
`this.template.querySelector('.slds-is-active').className= '';
```

`
Both of these approaches aren't working. Can someone please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

we dont need "." when we remove or add the class "slds-is-active"

it should be

```
 this.template.querySelector('.slds-is-active').classList.remove('slds-is-active');
```

here is an example
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/ycqTBcTN/1/edit